# how to log real destination endpoint of load balancer in apache camel

Tags: logging, apache-camel, load-balancing

With Apache Camel I want to send files to a ftp server and if this server becomes unreachable then I want to send files to a backup ftp server. I do it with load balancer

```
<route id="ftp.failover">
  <from uri="file:/path/to/files"/>
  <loadBalance inheritErrorHandler="false">
    <failover roundRobin="false" sticky="false"/>
    <to uri="ftp://ftp_host"/>
    <to uri="ftp://backup_ftp_host"/>
  </loadBalance>
  <log message="Sent ${headers}"/>
</route>
```

Now, I want to see in log to which ftp server each file was sent and only if it was sent. Unfortunately, my `<log />` message doesn't show any info about destination. I suppose that I need to add some ${out.header.foo} in log message but I can't imagine what header name I should specify instead of foo.
So the question: is there a way to get logged the real destination in case of load balance in apache camel?

**UPDATED**: [solution]

Thanks to **Vimsha**, the solution was simple. There is only one thing which I want to mention: the CamelInterceptedEndpoint header populates as is without sanitizing so passwords become visible if present in uri. Additional log entry slightly pollute log file also. So instead of `<log />` I simply rewrite CamelInterceptedEndpoint header.

```
<interceptSendToEndpoint uri="ftp:*">
    <setHeader headerName="CamelInterceptedEndpoint">
        <simple>${headers.CamelInterceptedEndpoint.replaceAll("\?.*","")}</simple>
    </setHeader>
</interceptSendToEndpoint>
```

After this my initial route began to log the real destination.

Also it is possible to simply sanitize the uri:

```
<setHeader headerName="CamelInterceptedEndpoint">
  <javaScript>
    org.apache.camel.util.URISupport.sanitizeUri(request.headers.get('CamelInterceptedEndpoint'))
  </javaScript>
</setHeader>
```

May be there is more convenient way to call camel's method but javascript is more simple to me.

Comment: I don't see any header being set by loadbalancer. An easy way would be to wrap your two destinations as tiny "direct" routes, with two steps: logging and ftp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an interceptor for ftp endpoints and log using the header `CamelInterceptedEndpoint`

```
<interceptSendToEndpoint uri="ftp:*">
   <log message="Sending to ${headers.CamelInterceptedEndpoint}"/>
</interceptSendToEndpoint>
```

Your full route will look something like this

```
<interceptSendToEndpoint uri="ftp:*">
   <log message="Sending to ${headers.CamelInterceptedEndpoint}"/>
</interceptSendToEndpoint>

<route id="ftp.failover">
  <from uri="file:/path/to/files"/>
  <loadBalance inheritErrorHandler="false">
     <failover roundRobin="false" sticky="false"/>
     <to uri="ftp://ftp_host"/>
     <to uri="ftp://backup_ftp_host"/>
  </loadBalance>
  <log message="Sent ${headers}"/>
</route>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is that you add messageHistory flag to CamelContext. It will log all balancer nodes and target node selected to send

```
<camelContext id="camel" messageHistory="true" debug="true">
```

Then in the log, you will see content like this

```
 RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)

[entitlementResourc] [to11              ] [direct:UEQSAPICalls                                                           ] [         0]
[route1            ] [loadBalance1      ] [loadBalance[http://localhost:28442,http://localhost:28443,http://localhost:284] [         0]
[route1            ] [to2               ] [http://localhost:28443                                                        ] [         0]
```